# How to print a list of custom properties of a QML object?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Having created a QML QtObject:

```
QtObject {
    property int p: 42
    property int q: 44
}
```

After storing it in a local variable `QObject *obj`, how to print all custom property names and possibly values (i.e. only `p` and `q` for the example above)? I'd like this to work for any class (not just `QtObject`) and not print properties that were already declared with `Q_PROPERTY`.

Clarification: by "custom" I do not mean properties added through `QObject::setProperty` that were not declared using `Q_PROPERTY`. I mean properties declared in QML through `property <type> <name>: <value>` notation that were not declared using `Q_PROPERTY` in `QObject` subclass for that QML object. Quick test shows that those properties do not come up in `QObject::dynamicPropertyNames`.

Comment: QtObject is the base class for every class in QML. So what do you mean when you said "not just QtObject"?

Comment: I mean that I want to get a list that excludes all properties that I've already included in `Q_PROPERTY` declaration of `QObject`'s subclass that I'm working on. It's about how to distinguish between them.

Comment: In your question, QML dynamic property is actually **QML custom property**. See, for example, documentation page    [Inline Link]( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html)    A QML custom property is different from a QObject dynamic property. So the name of the QML custom property is not included in the return value of `dynamicPropertyNames()`, and the object cannot receive a `QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent` when the property has changed value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All information about properties, invokable methods (*slots* too) and signals are stored by **QMetaObject** in every [*QObject*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#metaObject). If you want to list all properties in an object:

```
QObject *obj = findObjectMethod();
QMetaObject *meta = obj->metaObject();
int n = meta->propertyCount();
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  qDebug() << "Property: " << meta->property(i)->name();
}
```

Comment: I was trying something similar and I do prefer to do that from C++. However, how to not print all properties already declared with `Q_PROPERTY`?

Comment: I guess this is the best approach for my specific problem after all. And to get properties from QML not defined using `Q_PROPERTY`, you only have to filter out those from `staticMetaObject`.

Comment: @Xilexio there is another method, *QMetaObject::propertyOffset()* that returns you the index for the first property defined in the actual object that you are pointing to. I'm not sure (and I cannot try right now) but for your sample code, it should return the index for *p* property. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 8):

### C++ and QML approach

To print only dynamic property names, you can use the very aptly named [dynamicPropertyNames()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#dynamicPropertyNames) function of `QObject` from within an invokable C++ function:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int staticProperty READ staticProperty)
public:
    Object() {
        setProperty("dynamicProperty", 1);
    }

    int staticProperty() const {
        return 0;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void printDynamicPropertyNames() const {
        qDebug() << dynamicPropertyNames();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Object object;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("object", &object);
    engine.load("main.qml");

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Component.objectName: object.printDynamicPropertyNames()
}
```

Output:

```
("dynamicProperty")
```

---

### QML-only approach

If you want to print all properties of an object, *dynamic or not*, purely with QML, use JavaScript's [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) syntax:

> The for..in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var prop in rect) {
            print(prop += " (" + typeof(rect[prop]) + ") = " + rect[prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: objectName (string) = 
qml: parent (object) = null
qml: data (object) = [object Object]
qml: resources (object) = [object Object]
qml: children (object) = [object Object]
qml: x (number) = 0
qml: y (number) = 0
qml: z (number) = 0
qml: width (number) = 360
qml: height (number) = 360
qml: opacity (number) = 1
qml: enabled (boolean) = true
...
```

Comment: Properties declared in QML are not treated as dynamic properties by Qt. The approach in the other answer using QMetaObject works.

Comment: From my quick test, the answer you accepted will print out *only* static properties. I edited my answer days ago after re-reading your question, and have provided an additional solution in C++ that only prints out dynamic property names.

Comment: I put the quotation around "dynamic" to indicate that I do not mean dynamic properties set through `setProperty`, but new, not declared through `Q_PROPERTY` properties set in QML using `property <type> <name>: <value>`. I tested it and they do not come up as dynamic properties in Qt sense. I just did not have any other name for that. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Fair enough; that's the second time I read your question incorrectly. :p

Comment: Given this information I was able to check if a function exists in a specific item with `if(rect["myfunction") { rect.myfunction(); }`. Might anyone ever come across this kind of issue.

Comment: @Marnix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty might be a better alternative to that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To get "your" properties of an object in QML

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    for(var property in rect)
        if (property in rect.parent === false) {
            console.log("local property:", property, typeof(rect[property]))
        }
}
```